# AVD Dose not start, No Errors Either

Tags: avd-manager

I have my AVD setup with a Virtual Phone created, but when i click start. It shows me the window that it is starting the AVD, and then when the prograss bar gets done, the window closes and nothing starts up.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, turned out to be a fault with my graphics driver . Assuming you're running windows check your event logs for more info